# override the default WooCommerce products search form

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, search

how can I do override the default WooCommerce products search form on my custom WooTheme ?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exists the template `product-searchform.php`, you have to override it in your theme.

More information [here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) about how to override WooCommerce templates from your theme.

Basically the WooCommerce search forms returns only products and not also other post types because the product post type is specified in an hidden input:

`<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product" />`